# red velvet cake - cake flour?

Tags: cake, flour

I am looking to bake a red velvet cake, but I’ve seen different recipes, some use all purpose flour and some use cake flour. There are some diy cake flour recipes too since I don’t have cake flour. I’m wondering what’s the difference if I use all purpose flour instead of cake flour? Will it make a difference? I’m undecided on which recipe to use too so if you also have a suggestion that would be great, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cake flour is milled more finely than all purpose flour.  It also has a lower protein content, so less gluten is produced in the final product.  It is ideal for achieving the soft crumb of a cake.  That said, plenty of cakes are made with all purpose flour.  You would be able to perceive a difference in a side-by-side comparison.  In your own kitchen, with one cake, it is not going to matter too much.  I would suggest you sift your dry ingredients and move ahead with AP flour.  It will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

even if you have to use the substitute (APF + cornstarch), try it so you will know for yourself what the difference is. all i can tell you is that it creates a lighter, softer and more delicate crumb. many people like cakes better with this type of crumb.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to try that. I was just wondering if it was going to really affect the cake in a bad way if I just used AP flour. thanks!

Comment: sure :-) so did you try using it? how did it turn out?